# Firebase delay in response when handling multiple location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino

I will brief my project first. Its a 4WD robot which can be controlled over internet. I am using **esp8266 NodeMCU** as my mainboard.
For sending data over internet. I am using **firebase realtime database.**
The android app has the following features. It can control the robot movements in 2 different speeds.It will display live reading of 2 sensors (DHT11 and MQ2) and control 5 servos connected to nodemcu (Using seekbar bar to control each servo). **Everything is working properly individually. Like when i tested only with motors it was working fine (There was quick response as soon as I change direction from app). Similarly there was quick response from servos also when tested alone**.

**When i uploaded the full sketch (with motors, 5 servo, 2 sensors),I was getting delayed response from the motors and servos.
For eg : When the robot is moving forward direction and the backward direction button is pressed i will take around 2 sec for the robot to change it's direction. Even if its 2 sec it's getting too hard while controlling it.**

This is test code, which is giving quick response

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com"                  //Your Firebase Project URL goes here without "http:" , "\" and "/"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xxxxx"       //Your Firebase Database Secret goes here
#define WIFI_SSID "xxx"                                             //your WiFi SSID for which yout NodeMCU connects
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxx"    
int value = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
   Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);
  Firebase.set("S1", 0);

}

void loop() {
  value = Firebase.getInt("S1");
  if (value == 1) 
    Serial.println("Both Forward slow");

  else if(value == 2) 
    Serial.println("Both Forward fast");

  else if(value == 3)
    Serial.println("Both backward  slow");

  else if(value == 4) 
    Serial.println("Both backward  fast");
}
```

I even tried changing the if else ladder to switch case, no positive result.
As soon i pressed the button the value in the firebase is getting changed. So there is no problem with network.

The void loop in arduino is executing slowly.

Here is the complete code

```
#include <Servo.h> 
#include "DHT.h"       
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <FirebaseArduino.h>
#define FIREBASE_HOST "xxx-xxx.firebaseio.com"                  //Your Firebase Project URL goes here without "http:" , "\" and "/"
#define FIREBASE_AUTH "xxxx"       //Your Firebase Database Secret goes here
#define WIFI_SSID "xxx"                                             //your WiFi SSID for which yout NodeMCU connects
#define WIFI_PASSWORD "xxx"

#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
#define dht_dpin D7      // Connect Sensor to D3 pin
#define mq2_pin A0

Servo myservo1;
Servo myservo2;
Servo myservo3;
Servo myservo4;
Servo myservo5;

#define ENA D5
#define ENB D6
int fast = 1023;
int slow = 511;

DHT dht(dht_dpin, DHTTYPE);
int S1 = 0;
int speed_value;
int temp_value;
int smoke_value;
int humidity_value;
String servo1_value, servo2_value, servo3_value, servo4_value, servo5_value;

int servo1;
int servo2;
int servo3;
int servo4;
int servo5;


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(9600);
  myservo1.attach(D0);
  myservo2.attach(D8);
  myservo3.attach(3);
  myservo4.attach(1);
  myservo5.attach(10);
  pinMode(A0, INPUT);
  pinMode(D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D3, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D4, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D5, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D6, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(D7, INPUT);

  dht.begin();


  WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
  Serial.print("connecting");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.print(".");
    delay(500);
  }
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("connected: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
  Firebase.begin(FIREBASE_HOST, FIREBASE_AUTH);

}

void loop() {

  humidity_value = dht.readHumidity();
  temp_value = dht.readTemperature();
  smoke_value = analogRead(A0);

  S1 = Firebase.getInt("S1");
  speed_value = Firebase.getInt("Speed");
  Firebase.setInt("Temperature", temp_value);
  Firebase.setInt("Humidity",humidity_value);

  if(smoke_value > 500)
    Firebase.setString("Smoke","True");
  else
      Firebase.setString("Smoke","False");

  servo1_value = Firebase.getString("Servo1");
  servo2_value = Firebase.getString("Servo2");
  servo3_value = Firebase.getString("Servo3");
  servo4_value = Firebase.getString("Servo4");
  servo5_value = Firebase.getString("Servo5");


  myservo1.write(servo1_value.toInt());
  myservo2.write(servo2_value.toInt());
  myservo3.write(servo3_value.toInt());
  myservo4.write(servo4_value.toInt());
  myservo5.write(servo5_value.toInt());

  Serial.print(servo1_value.toInt());
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(servo2_value.toInt());
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(servo3_value.toInt());
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(servo4_value.toInt());
  Serial.print("\t");
  Serial.print(servo5_value.toInt());
  Serial.println();


  if (speed_value == 1) {
    if (S1 == 0) {
      stop_();
    }
    else if (S1 == 1) {
      forward_slow();
    }
    else if (S1 == 2) {
      backward_slow();
    }
    else if (S1 == 3) {
      left_slow();
    }
    else if (S1 == 4) {
      right_slow();
    }
  }
  else if (speed_value == 2) {
    if (S1 == 0) {
      stop_();
    }
    else if (S1 == 1) {
      forward_fast();
    }
    else if (S1 == 2) {
      backward_fast();
    }
    else if (S1 == 3) {
      left_fast();
    }
    else if (S1 == 4) {
      right_fast();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are writing/reading multiple fields. That obviously slows everything down.

Comment: @gre_gor Is there any way to get rid of this ? Or is there any alternative for firebase.